# Accessing CSS3 media queries from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Now, finally after 12 years, when all the world is hopping into CSS3 media query and responsive design bandwagon a problem remains.

How one can know from Javascript which media queries are

- present in HTML code: this should be simple element traversing, but are there smarter ways?
- effective (query evaluates to true)

... so you can add special code paths to support mobile, tablets, etc. in Javascript code? Eventually one could write function `isMobile()` and use it as a flag for certain actions specific to small screen estate.

Comment: `document.styleSheets[i].media[j]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have a specific object in your page that gets a known style from your CSS for each media query of interest.  You can then read that style off the object with `getComputedStyle()` and see what was assigned to it and that would tell you which media query had precedence.

Comment: Any ideas of "invisible" styles I could use hinting, e.g. on <body>? The styles which would not affect layout, but become readable via getComputedStyles()?

Comment: You can use a div that is positioned absolutely with a `left: -1000px`.  Because it's `position: absolute`, it won't affect the layout of the page.  Because it's `left: 1000px`, it won't be visible and won't cause scrollbar.  Then, set a CSS width on it with a media query rule and you can read that width with getComputedStyles().  jQuery uses this trick to calclulate things when it needs something laid out by the browser, but not visible.